# PHP response fades away

Tags: php, ajax, xampp

I am trying to get response trough ajax,my code (index.html) :

```
<button id="register">Register</button>
<p id="result">xxx</p>

<script>
    $("#register").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'registration.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

and php (registration.php):

```
<?php 
echo "yyy"
?>
```

I am working with xampp, I get response but it fades from page instantly. And again xxx is present inside p tag, does anyone know what is the reason why this happens.
Thanks

Comment: What fades away from the page? Can you try to describe the flow of events more detailed?

Comment: surely you are pulling in the necessary jquery files...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when you click the button to get your response, it also refreshes the page in your browser. You can try the following to prevent this:

```
<script>
$("#register").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  $.ajax({
    url:'registration.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
      $("#result").html(response)
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

This prevents your browser from doing what it normally does when you click a button.Any button inside `<form>`tags will automatically send a `GET` request within the current window, causing the page to refresh. The other alternative to `preventDefault()` is to use the attribute `type="button"` on your button and this will stop the button from being a `type="submit"` button.

You can read more detailed information about the function I've used here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
- https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, it helped ! :)

Comment: This is correct. Any button inside `<form>` tags will automatically send a GET request within the current window, causing the page to refresh. The other alternative to `preventDefault()` is to use the attribute `type="button"` on your button and this will stop the button from being a `type="submit"` button.

Comment: @GoranGrle If this answer has helped then consider upvoting and marking as accepted (by clicking the green arrow on the left)

Comment: @GoranGrle : Or you can treat as simple button type as `<button type="button"  id="register">Register</button>`

Comment: Thanks @JustCarty for detailing out the technical process of what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Just prevent page before submitting.

```
<input type='submit' id='register'>
<div id='result'></div>
$("#register").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
  url:'registration.php',
  type: 'GET',
  success:function(response){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
  }
 })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that: running an AJAX call itself never refreshes anything, and what is the connection to "real time" here?

Comment: I still don't get it: both POST and GET can be used to load new data, and using AJAX, both can be used without reloading the page - that's the main point of using AJAX, independent of the HTTP method being used. So, can you explain why switching from POST to GET makes any difference?

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. Linked content might change, and that would make your answer useless.

Comment: Please add such information to the answer itself, not to the comment section. And after all, I still don't get why this should solve the problem: why is there a difference in using a cached version of `registration.php` (as would be used by your solution plus explanation)?